# UnsupportedOperationException using paint.getTextBounds

Tags: android

I got following error message:

```
main.xml: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Stacktrace says:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nativeGetStringBounds(Paint_Delegate.java:897)
at android.graphics.Paint.nativeGetStringBounds(Paint.java)
at android.graphics.Paint.getTextBounds(Paint.java:1798)
```

Within my code I have set up a simple test case to figure out where the problem is:

```
public class test extends View {

public test(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    p.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

    canvas.drawText("hello", 100, 100, p);

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    p.getTextBounds("2", 0, 1, bounds);
}

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Heres the complete stack trace:

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nativeGetStringBounds(Paint_Delegate.java:897)
at android.graphics.Paint.nativeGetStringBounds(Paint.java)
at android.graphics.Paint.getTextBounds(Paint.java:1798)
at myOwnSpace.testproject.test.onDraw(test.java:39)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9029)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2508)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2123)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2506)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2123)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2506)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2123)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9032)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2508)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2123)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9032)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:473)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:316)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:283)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1506)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1312)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1043)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:870)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(LayoutEditor.java:365)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1067)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:607)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.selectDefaultPage(AndroidXmlEditor.java:308)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.addPages(AndroidXmlEditor.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2863)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2682)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:373)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:526)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:843)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1235)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3783)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1383)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1195)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3629)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3284)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I'm guessing your problem isn't where you think it is. Post more of the stack trace - there's normally a 'Caused by' entry. Also, post your main.xml file.

Comment: @MisterSquonk I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, I just posted the whole stacktrace but coudln't find a "caused by" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
p.getTextBounds(new String("2"), 0, 1, bounds);
```